# What is causing the error loading worldmap

Tags: windows, r-maptools, rworldmap

I get the folowing error when trying to load rworldmap. I am running the latest version of r ie 4.2.3  and have tried downloading and installing again, but has no effect
Any solutions? I am trying to plot a map using code that worked last Autumn

> library('maptools') # load libraries from these packages
> library('rgeos')
> library('rworldmap')
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rworldmap’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required

Tried downloading and reinstalling r but no help